# How make IDs available again when deleting canvas items?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to create, delete and then - again - create items on a canvas. It would come in really handy if the newly created items would have the same IDs as the ones before.

I tried to handle this by deleting the itemswith `canvas.delete(tag)` and also detaging the items with `canvas.dtag(dot, ID-of-dot)`. Noting worked so far. Here's an example to show what I mean:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

x = 0
y = 25

def oval():
    global x, y
    coords = [x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5]
    if x < 40:
        x += 10
    else:
        x = 10
        canv.delete("dots")
    coords = [x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5]
    canv.create_oval(*coords, tags="dots")

    dot_list = canv.find_withtag("dots")
    txt.delete(1.0, "end")
    txt.insert(0.0, dot_list)

canv = tk.Canvas(root, width=50, height=50)
canv.grid(row=0, column=0)
but1 = tk.Button(root, width=10, height=1, text="Push Me", command=oval)
but1.grid(row=0, column=1)
txt = tk.Text(width=10, height=1)
txt.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to have the same IDs (1, 2, 3, 4) repeating themselves and not to just keep counting as it the case here. Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT**

So as it seems you can't reuse IDs but for a general solution you could take @martineau 's approach and handle an ID-Dict to assign the IDs.
For this specific example a workaround I found is enumerating over the list of ovals and just take the count as the output:

```
txt.delete(1.0, "end")
for i, dot in enumerate(canv.find_withtag("dots")):
    txt.insert("end", i+1)
```

Comment: I don't believe you have any control over the ids. A possible workaround would be to maintain your own dictionary that mapped a "logical" or "application" id of your own choosing, like say a string or integer, to the latest `Canvas` id that was assigned to the item.

Comment: If you're creating one new canvas item for each one you delete, and it's the same type of item, just reconfigure the existing item - `Canvas.itemconfig()`, `Canvas.coords()`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t reuse canvas item ids.